# "Будь здоровий!" чи "на здоров’я!"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Коли людина чхнула, як насправді слід промовляти: "будь здоровий!" чи "на здоров’я!"?

Адже ще кілька років тому завжди чула першу фразу, а от останнім часом щось популярнішою стала друга.

Я вважаю, що, ймовірно, **побажання** "***будь здоровий***" було первинним, а вже з плином часу щось могло на це повпливати і видозмінитись на **ствердження** "***на здоров’я!***". Якщо це справді так, то слід тоді вживати першу фразу як ту, яка з’явилась швидше. Що ж це таке могло тоді бути? Можливо, я взагалі тоді помиляюсь і ці явища розвивались одночасно... Хоча ду-у-уже сумніваюсь. Скажіть, будь ласка, та, якщо це можливо, проілюструйте відповідними джерелами відмінність у вживанні, якщо така є.

Підтвердження чи спростування моїх думок для себе не знайшла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Відмінність вживання виразів взята з СУМ-20

> [(36) Будь здоро́в](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6191&page=226) (здоро́вий, здорове́нький) <Бу́дьте здоро́ві
>   (здорове́нькі)>: **а)** уживається як усталена форма прощання або рідше
>   вітання при зустрічі з ким-небудь. *[Квятковська:] Ну, будь же
>   здоровенька та веселенька та нас швидше потіш!* (М. Старицький); *–
>   Добривечір вам!.. Будьте здорові! – сказали бурлаки до хазяїна* (І.
>   Нечуй-Левицький); *[Кассандра:] Прощай же, Ономаю! [Ономай:] Будь
>   здорова* (Леся Українка); *Потім він простяг Альоші руку. – Будь
>   здоровий, скульпторе* (І. Микитенко); **б)** (з часткою і) уживається для
>   вираження чиєї-небудь безпорадності, безвиході; нічого не можна
>   вдіяти. *А що, думаю собі, коли не в ті двері? Дадуть по карку, і будь
>   здоровий* (М. Ю. Тарновський); **в)** (перев. із словоспол. такий (так),
>   що) уживається для підкреслення чого-небудь, наголошення на чомусь
>   (перев. позитивному, якісному). *А рейси такі, що – здоров тільки будь!*
>   (С. Олійник);
>
> [(3) На здоро́в'я](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35817&page=226) (на здоро́в'ячко), у знач. виг. – уживається під
>   час пригощання або як відповідь на подяку тому, кого пригощають. –
>   *Питки хочеш, сину? – спитався, підійшовши, Грицько. – Пий на здоров'я*
>   (Панас Мирний); *– Одначе призволяйтеся, матушки, на здоров'ячко, ще й
>   у кишені наховайте та повезіть дітям на гостинець* (І.
>   Нечуй-Левицький); *– От спасибі тобі, Юхиме, – за останнім снопом
>   подякувала Катря. – На здоров'я, молодице, – відповів Юхим* (А.
>   Головко);

[Чому ми бажаємо здоров'я людині, яка чхає?](https://infokava.com/uk/47594-pochemu-my-zhelaem-zdorovya-chykhnuvshemu-cheloveku.html)

> У сучасному світі англійці кажуть: «Хай благословить тебе Бог!» —
>   німці і слов'яни бажають здоров'я, а італійці — щастя. На Близькому і
>   Середньому Сході кланяються у бік кого, хто чхнув і плескають у
>   долоні.

[Навіщо говорити людині "будь здоров" якщо він вже чхає](http://likarnya.pp.ua/navishho-govoriti-ljudini-bud-zdorov-jakshho-vin.html)

> «Будь здоровий». Людина чхає. Люди кажуть йому «Б.З.». Вважається, що
>   так. вони висловлюють йому бажання здоров'я. Якщо ж «Б.З.» не
>   говорять, то людина, яка чхнув, відчуває себе ображеним, вважає, що
>   люди відчувають АЛЕ до нього, відчуває образу.

На мою думку, краще використовувати фразу ***"будь здоровий"***. Люди бажають ***"будь здоровий"*** оскільки вважається чхання прояв початку хвороби, хоча це не завжди так.